# Выполнение скрипта через временые промежутки

Tags: javascript

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, вот есть скрипт, как лучще его переделать чтобы он выполнялся через равные промежутки времени (примерно секунд 10, например)

```
        var callback = {
            success: function(o) {
             document.getElementById("numItems_info").innerHTML = o.responseText;
            }
        }

        var connectionObject = YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest("GET",      "http://localhost/index.php?module=NumItems", callback);
```

Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
setInterval(function(){ //some code},10000);
```

Посмотрите в сторону этой функции

Comment: спасибо! Сейчас буду внедрять.